# Python Implementation of Bartlett Periodogram

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to implement Periodogram in Python based on the description from [Bartlett's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_method), and compared the result with those from Scipy, by setting overlap=0, use window='boxcar' (rectangle window). However, my result is off by some scale factor. Can someone points out what was wrong with my code? Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal


def my_bartlett_periodogram(x, fs, nperseg, nfft):    
    nsegments = len(x) // nperseg
    psd = np.zeros(nfft)
    for segment in x.reshape(nsegments, nperseg):
        psd += np.abs(np.fft.fft(segment))**2 / nfft
    psd[0] = 0   # important!!
    psd /= nsegments
    psd = psd[0 : nfft//2]
    freq = np.linspace(0, fs/2, nfft//2)
    return freq, psd

def plot_output(t, x, f1, psd1, f2, psd2):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1, figsize=(12,15))
    axs[0].plot(t[:300], x[:300])
    axs[1].plot(freq1, psd1)
    axs[2].plot(freq2, psd2)
    axs[0].set_title('Input (len=8192, fs=512)')
    axs[1].set_title('Bartlett Periodogram (nfft=512, zero-overlap, no-window)')
    axs[2].set_title('Scipy Periodogram (nfft=512, zero-overlap, no-window)')
    axs[0].set_xticks([])
    axs[2].set_xlabel('Freq (Hz)')
    plt.show()

# Run
fs = nfft = nperseg = 512
t = np.arange(8192) / fs
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*150*t)
freq1, psd1 = my_bartlett_periodogram(x, fs, nperseg, nfft)
freq2, psd2 = signal.welch(x, fs, nperseg=nperseg, nfft=nfft, window='boxcar', noverlap=0)
plot_output(t, x, freq1, psd1, freq2, psd2)
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I just found that, the DC component of the my calculation must be set to 0 or else the output won't match when the input has a DC offset in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR:

Nothing wrong with the code. But `welch` returns the *power spectral density*, which is the power spectrum times `fs` and it compensates for cutting away half the spectrum by multiplying with 2.

To compensate, `psd2 * fs / 2` should be very similar to `psd`.

---

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartlett%27s_method) the calculation of `psd` seems correct:

> 1. The original N point data segment is split up into K (non-overlapping) data segments, each of length M
> 2. For each segment, compute the periodogram by computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT version which does not divide by M), then computing the squared magnitude of the result and dividing this by M.
> 3. Average the result of the periodograms above for the K data segments.

So whom shall we trust more, Wikipedia or scipy? I would tend towards the latter, but we can find out for ourselves. According to [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) the integral over the squared signal should be the same as the integral over the sqared FFT magnitude. Since the Periodogram is obtained from the squared FFT the theorem should hold approximately.

```
print(np.mean(y**2))  # 1.499727698431174
print(np.mean(psd))  # (1.4999999999999991+0j)
print(np.mean(psd2))  # 0.0058365758754863788
```

That's close enough for `psd`, so let's assume it's correct. But I refuse to believe that scipy should be so blatantly wrong! Let's take a closer look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) and see what they have to say about the `scaling` argument (emphasis mine):

> Selects between computing the power spectral density (‘density’) where Pxx has units of **`V**2/Hz`** and computing the power spectrum (‘spectrum’) where Pxx has units of V**2, if x is measured in V and fs is measured in Hz. Defaults to ‘density’

Uh-huh! `welch`'s result is the *power spectral density*, which means it has units of Power per Hz. However, we compared it against the signal power. If we multiply `psd2` with the sampling rate to get rid of the 1/Hz units it's the same as `psd`. Well, except for a factor 2. This factor is meant to compensate for cutting away half the spectrum. If we set `return_onesided=False` to get the full spectrum that factor is gone.

Comment: But the description from the wikipedia said "For each segment, compute the periodogram by computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT version which does not divide by M), then computing the squared magnitude of the result and dividing this by M". Perhaps the wikipedia description was wrong?

Comment: @ScoodoodC Wikipedia is actually right but the `welch` function follows a different convention. See updated answer.

Comment: Hi kazemakase, your answer really help! Thank you very much. I believe you last sentence has a typo. I believe you meant "return_onesided=False" in order to get a for full spectrum power. I had confirmed on my end, "return_onesided=False" and multiply with fs gave me the exact same result.

Comment: @ScoodoodC well spotted. True is the default and we need to explicitly set it to false to get the full spectrum.

Comment: I believe your Parseval's calculation of y is incorrect. Should it be `np.sum(y**2)` instead of `np.mean(y**2)`? The wikipedia formula did not divide the sum by N for the time-domain signal.

Comment: @ScoodoodC You read the wikipedia article correctly. The article talks about the Fourier transform but here we  deal with the periodogram. The periodogram is basically a downsampled version of the FFT, so I used the mean to compensate for the different sizes of `y` and `psd`. Alternatively, I could have used the sum and applied a correction factor of 2*16 to the periodogram to account for the segmentation.